# Whats the correct scheme of MVC pattern?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, spring-mvc, design-patterns, model-view-controller, controller

Does the controller update the view (first image) or model should update the view (second image)?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the official documentation, the controller is responsible for handling requests. If applicable, it uses model data to update the view. So, image 1 I would say!

[ASP.NET Core MVC](https://learn.microsoft.com/el-gr/aspnet/core/mvc/overview)

Comment: Can you provide a link?

Comment: Edited answer with link

Comment: @Alex78191Can you please accept my answer? Or explain why you don't?